# ¿Cómo evitar el error de foreign key constraint en phpmyadmin y en php?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Muy buenas!

Estoy realizando una pequeña practica para recordar después de haber estado estudiando otra vez al php y en conocimiento al MySqli (estilo procedure), al crear el base de datos y las tablas correspondientes. Nunca jamas había visto este error después de hacer el formulario para añadir registros de una tabla y luego rellenarla y aparece esto:

[image: PhpMyAdmin Error]

[image: Base de datos actualizada con primary keys y foreign keys.]

```
Editarusuario.php
```

```html
<?php
$msg = $Usuario = $Nombre = $Apellido = $ID_perfil = $ID_estado = $password = $fecha_actual = NULL;

if(isset($_POST['editar'])) {
 $Usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
 $Nombre = $_POST['apellido'];
 $ID_perfil = $_POST['id_perfil'];
 $ID_estado = $_POST['id_estado'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 $fecha_actual = $_POST['fecha'];

 if ($Usuario && $Nombre && $ID_perfil && $ID_estado && $password && $fecha_actual) {

  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "webpractica");

  if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   printf("Falló la conexión: $s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
   exit();
  }

  $query = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE Usuario SET Usuario = '$Usuario', Nombre = '$Nombre', password = '$password', Fecha_Creacion = '$fecha_actual' WHERE ID_perfil = '$id_perfil' AND ID_estado = '$id_estado')");
  if(!$query) {
   printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
  } else {
   $msg = "Los datos se editaron correctamente";
  }
 }
}
echo $msg;
?>
```

Este error tiene algo relacionado por la relación de las tablas o es el query o se permite modificar las restricciones del Foreign Key?

Espero atentamente sus comentarios y soluciones al respecto.
Saludos!

**EDIT:** Después de estudiar intensamente sobre mysql y tratar de insertar las tablas sin necesidad de PHP (a menos que lo haga bien, modifiqué un poco por poner AND, no sabia si era necesario por los dos foreign keys y se muestra el error en nuevas imagenes, el base de datos esta actualizado con PK Y FK.)

**EDIT 2:** Descubri que al cortar la relacion de la tabla usuario con anexo, funciona con los demás tablas, pero al dejar rellenando la tabla con php todo bien, pero, estuve tratando conectar la relación id_estado de la tabla usuario con id_estado de anexo, tira el mismo error. (FK con FK)
Dejo los detalles del contenido de las tablas.

[image: Tabla estado]

[image: Tabla usuarios]

[image: Tabla Perfil]

Comment: No tiene que ver con tu problema pero es algo que deberías tener en cuenta. Usar funciones como `strip_tags()` o `htmlentities()` entre muchos otros métodos a la hora de recuperar datos mediante `$_GET` o `$_POST` te puede salvar de ataques XSS (Cross SIte Scripting) a tu página web y base de datos. Aquí te dejo un link con algo de información que te puede ser útil [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29)

Comment: Mira te sugiero que agregues captura de el contenido de las tablas Usuarios, Perfil y Estado

Comment: @AdrianaHernández esta tomada la captura de las tablas. Deje también el EDIT 2 por detalles del descubrimiento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema se debe a que no existe la `acción` que tiene el id que estas insertando con la variable `$id_accion`.

Comprueba en `phpmyadmin` que la `acción` con dicho id exista.

Además, veo **(en el diagrama)** que tienes una relación entre `log` y `tipo_anexo` pero no veo la fk en ninguna de las 2 tablas. Sin embargo veo que en `log` tienes una fk hacia `anexo` lo cual no se ve representado en el diagrama.

Entonces, si la tabla `log` tiene una fk hacia `anexo` entonces sí, como dices, tienes que tener al menos un registro de `anexo` en BD (ademas del de `accion`) para poder insertar un `log` con un `anexo` referenciado por `$id_anexo`. Pero... si la tabla `log` es quien tendría la fk de `tipo_anexo` entonces a la hora de insertar un `log` pasa lo mismo y también tienes que tener al menos un registro en la tabla `tipo_anexo` al que puedas referenciar

Saludos.

Comment: Revisé en las tablas relacionadas con tabla log, solo la tabla accion si tiene valores pero en la tabla, ahi no hay valores, sino vacíos, será ese problema? Y al tratar de rellenar el formulario una vez más para asegurarme (esta vez añadiendo el id accion que relacione de la tabla accion) y si resultó aunque salió otro error, que se habla sobre la tabla Anexo y tipo_anexo. Lo que me hace preguntarme es, se debería haber rellenado los demás tablas para que se pueda añadir con las relaciones?

Comment: No puedes insertar un log que tenga una acción cuyo id no exista en la tabla `accion` de la base de datos. También puede que tengas mal hecha las relaciones entre tablas, porque además veo que tienes una relación entre `log` y `tipo_anexo` sin embargo no veo la `fk`

Comment: disculpa, se me cayó el internet hace días, el log, no debería haber tenido un id_anexo cierto? aunque lo haya hecho, puse dos fk, que es el id_anexo de log, id_accion del log (relacionando con la tabla de id accion) y ah, una consulta más. He estado pensando en aplicar el query de Update, es el query correcto? `$query = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE log SET Fecha_Creacion = '$fecha_actual', usuario = '$usuario' WHERE id_log = '$id_log', id_anexo = '$id_anexo', id_accion = '$id_accion')"); `
Espero su respuesta, muchos saludos.

Comment: creo que he arreglado las tablas, pero aun asi me tira error todavía, no entiendo, creo que el error se relaciona más a la tabla de anexo. Es por la relación? no entiendo bien

Comment: Que error te muestra? es el mismo error? Edita la pregunta y agrega lo nuevo que hiciste en las tablas

Comment: está editada la pregunta y actualizada.

Comment: Al final creo que tenias razón, porque al reaprenderme otra vez la entidad-relacion, el UML y modelo relacional. Mi error propio fue que originalmente pensaba que la tabla tipo_anexo debia relacionar con Anexo. Por eso se tiró ese error, fue mi equivocación. Haciendo vaciar todas las tablas, lo primero debia empezar con tablas pequeñas y luego relacionarlas, de ahi, usuarios relaciona con anexo teniendo los FK y al final funcionó las relaciones. Ahora debería insertar los registros sin problema. Dejo la aceptación de voto como correcta. Saludos.

Comment: Ok, gracias. Me alegro que te hayas aclarado. Te recomiendo que hagas un par de prácticas mas para que te quede bien claro como hacer los modelos de datos relacionales bien hechos. Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

El error se lanza porque estas intentando insertar un valor en una columna que tiene una restricción de clave foránea (**acción**). Lo que significa que solo puedes insertar ids que ya estén presentes en la tabla **acción**.

Lo ideal es que en el código php verifiques que ya se exista el elemento de **accion** que quieres asociar con **log** antes de insertarlo. Ademas **id_accion** es un entero y lo estas pasando  al query como cadena.