# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint

Tags: php, pdo

Estoy tratando de hacer un insert con PDO y me sale ese error

¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Este es el codigo de mis tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE `productos` (
  `Id_Producto` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Nombre_Producto` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Precio_Producto` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Descripcion_producto` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Id_Tipo_Producto` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Id_Factura` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_detalle_proveedores` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `existencia_producto` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imagen_producto` longblob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id_Producto`),
  KEY `fk_Productos_Factura_idx` (`Id_Factura`),
  KEY `fk_Productos_Detalle_Proveedores_idx` (`id_detalle_proveedores`),
  KEY `fk_Productos_Tipo_Producto_idx` (`Id_Tipo_Producto`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Productos_Detalle_Proveedores` FOREIGN KEY (`id_detalle_proveedores`) REFERENCES `detalle_proveedores` (`id_detalle_proveedores`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Productos_Factura` FOREIGN KEY (`Id_Factura`) REFERENCES `factura` (`Id_Folio_Factura`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Productos_Tipo_Producto` FOREIGN KEY (`Id_Tipo_Producto`) REFERENCES `tipo_producto` (`Id_Tipo_Producto`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=74 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

---

Y esta es la otra tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE `tipo_producto` (
  `Id_Tipo_Producto` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Nombre_tipo_Producto` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id_Tipo_Producto`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Este es el código con el que hago el insert:

```
public function insertarData($datos=array())
    {                           


        $sql=$this->conexion->prepare("insert into productos (nombre_producto,precio_producto,descripcion_producto,Id_Tipo_Producto,id_factura,id_detalle_proveedores,existencia_producto,imagen_producto) values (:nombre,:precio,:descripcion,:tipo,:factura,:lote,:existencia,:foto)");


        $sql->bindParam(':nombre',$nombre);
        $sql->bindParam(':precio',$precio);
        $sql->bindParam(':descripcion',$descripcion);
        $sql->bindParam(':tipo',$tipo);
        $sql->bindParam(':factura',$fact);
        $sql->bindParam(':lote',$lote);
        $sql->bindParam(':existencia',$existencia);
        $sql->bindParam(':foto',$foto);


        $nombre=$datos[0];
        $precio=$datos[1];
        $descripcion=$datos[2];
        $tipo=$datos[3];        
        $lote=$datos[4];
        $existencia=$datos[5];
        $foto=$datos[6];
        $fact=NULL;


        $sql->execute();    


         // $this->conexion->exec($sql);

    }


<?php 
require "Parametros.php";

class Conexion
{
    public $conexion=null;

    public function __construct(){

        $parametros=sprintf('mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s',Parametros::HOST,Parametros::DBNAME);
        try 
        {
            $this->conexion = new PDO($parametros, Parametros::USUARIO, Parametros::PASSWORD,array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));           
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) 
        {
            echo "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
            die();          
        }                                   
    }
}
```

---

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`punto_de_venta`.`productos`, CONSTRAINT `fk_Productos_Tipo_Producto` FOREIGN KEY (`Id_Tipo_Producto`) REFERENCES `tipo_producto` (`Id_Tipo_Producto`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) in C:\xamppp\htdocs\PRACTICAS\Web_Petco\model\Productos.php:44 Stack trace: #0 C:\xamppp\htdocs\PRACTICAS\Web_Petco\model\Productos.php(44): PDOStatement->execute() #1 C:\xamppp\htdocs\PRACTICAS\Web_Petco\controller\ControllerFormProductos.php(16): Productos->insertarData(Array) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xamppp\htdocs\PRACTICAS\Web_Petco\model\Productos.php on line 44

Comment: Necesitas que el Tipo_producto que insertar exista realmente.

Comment: El campo `Id_Tipo_Producto` debe existir en la tabla de tipos de productos, sino se rompe la integridad referencial, es decir, estás haciendo referencia a una clave primaria inexistente.

Comment: de hecho se me paso comentar eso si tengo los datos debidos, primero llene la tabla tipo_producto y la de productos despues para que pudiera tomar los datos de la foranea... HELP:(

Comment: Básicamente tus datos están violando la integridad, el **Id_Tipo_Producto** que insertes en la tabla productos debe existir primero en la tabla **tipo_producto**.

Comment: es que si tengo existentes los datos, es lo raro:\

Comment: Creo que tengo tu mismo problema hace como un mes, pero recomiendo que veas la diagrama de tu base de datos, por los FK y PK (llave primaria y secundaria) [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75427/como-evitar-el-error-de-foreign-key-constraint-en-phpmyadmin-y-en-php ] yo mismo resolvi el problema al ver bien que pasaba con las relaciones.

Comment: Gracias voy a darle un vistazo porque enserio que ya intente de todo. Pero seguiré buscando gracias.